# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list' error:

Tags: python-3.x

I was trying to add elements using slicing. Also I think I gave wrong arguments for self. what am I supposed to give? im new to coding. looking for some knowledge.

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

```
class Solution:
    def maxSubArray(self,A):
        sum_2=[]

        for i in range(0,len(A)):
            for j in range(1,len(A)-1):


                sum_1 = A[i]+A[:j]
                sum_2.append(sum_1)
        print(sum_2)
        print(max(sum_2))

s=Solution
q=[-2,1,-3,4,-1,2,1,-5,4]

s.maxSubArray('w',q)
```

expected: 6
actual:8

Comment: `A[i]` is getting the element in the array at index `i`. `A[:j]` is getting a subset of the array from `0` to `j`. Ergo, `A[i]+A[:j]` is trying to add an `int` and a `list`, which isn't going to fly.

Comment: That method probably doesn't need to be in a class. And `s=Solution` probably doesn't do what you think it does. You're essentially giving the `Solution` class an alias. As opposed to what I assume you're trying to do, which is assign an instance of the `Solution` class to variable `s`. Which would look like this: `s=Solution()`

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in this line:

```
sum_1 = A[i] + A[:j]
```

you should change it with:

```
sum_1 = [A[i]] + A[:j]
```